# How to 'encrypt' a file

Tags: python

Just trimmed this down big time

I have an overall assignment that must read a file, encrypt it and then write the encrypted data to a new file.

what i've tried is this:

```
filename=input("Enter file name:")
fr=open(filename)
keep_going=0
data = fr.readline()
fw=open('encrypted_file.txt', 'w')
for x in range(len(data)):
    fw.write(data[x])       
fw.close()
fr.close()
```

Comment: What encryption algorithm you want to use?

Comment: any encryption algorithm would work as long as i can decrypt it later as well. i tried going about the direct data.replace method but that didn't work out.

Comment: @Borja `hashlib` doesn't contain encryption/decryption functions. This lib can be used only for hash calculation

Comment: just included the guidelines to this assignment

Comment: What specifically are you stuck on?

Comment: I'm stuck on the part that changes the actual characters.

Comment: There's too much information here. The entire assignment description and File IO isn't relevant to your specific question. I'd recommend trimming it down to exactly the issue you're having (string manipulation?)

Comment: For simplicity, you should focus first on reading in the entire file into memory (a string), then manipulating that string, then writing the new string to the output file.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what i am stuck on. I am trying to figure out how exactly i can do the manipulating part using my own key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is just to exchange the letters in a string with others that you specify, then the solution is the following:

```
decrypted = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' #normal alphabet
encrypted = 'MNBVCXZLKJHGFDSAPOIUYTREWQ' #your "crypted" alphabet

#Encription
text = 'cryptme' #the string to be crypted
encrypted_text = ''
for letter in text:
    encrypted_text += encrypted[decrypted.find(letter)]
print encrypted_text
#will print BOWAUFC

#Decription
text = encrypted_text #"BOWAUFC" in this example
decrypted_text = ''
for letter in text:
    decrypted_text += decrypted[encrypted.find(letter)]
print decrypted_text
#will print cryptme
```

Note that your "crypted alphabet" do not convert any white space or any symbols but the lowercase letters, if you have other symbols in your text you have to include them as well.

However, this is not the proper way to encrypt anything! As suggested by others already, look up for a proper encryption algorithm.

Comment: This is what i have been looking for. I'll have to do more research to find out the correct way then. Thank you very much.

Comment: Suggestion: Instead of using `str.find()`, I'd recommend creating a dictionary mapping for encryption and one for decryption with  `dict(zip())`.

Comment: Yes, that could be another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look into Simple Crypt, this all depends on the level of security you want.

If I understand your question enough, Simple Crypt should do the job that you need.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simple-crypt

Comment: That will require a considerable more work. If I understand you correctly you'll need to create a library for your key, that's assuming you're wanting to use the same one throughout multiple files. Not quite sure as to why your own key is necessary, it seems as if you're trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I can use a very simple key.
For example:
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz --> qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple implementation of the [Vigenère Cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher) I made:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase as alphabet

val = {}
for x in xrange(len(alphabet)):
    val[alphabet[x]] = x
    val[x] = alphabet[x]

encrypt = lambda a, b: ''.join(val[(val[a[i]]+val[b[i%len(b)]])%26] for i in xrange(len(a)))
decrypt = lambda a, b: ''.join(val[(val[a[i]]-val[b[i%len(b)]])%26] for i in xrange(len(a)))
```

Where `a` is the message and `b` is the key (I know it's written a bit tersely, but it was for a code golf competition). There are plenty of ciphers out there; you don't have to use this one, and probably shouldn't. It is just meant to get you thinking about possible ways to go about doing this. A very simple cipher that I think is good for your purposes is the [Caesar Cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher).

One other thing that I'd like to point out is that your code doesn't look to modular -- one of your teacher's requirements -- right now. I'd recommend breaking it down to a function to open a file, a function to perform the actual **cryption, and a "main" function to take the user's input and call the other functions.

Best of luck to you!

Comment: Thank you, I will do just that.