# Change the values of a list without using index

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

```
def apply_coder(text, coder):
    """
    Applies the coder to the text. Returns the encoded text.

    text: string
    coder: dict with mappings of characters to shifted characters
    returns: text after mapping coder chars to original text
    """

    coder_dict = coder
    text_list = list(text)
    for letter in text_list:
        if letter in coder_dict:
            letter = coder_dict[letter]
            print letter
    return ''.join(text_list)
```

Example:
    apply_coder("Hello, world!", build_encoder(3)) should return

> 'Khoor,czruog!'

Instead, it returns

> "Hello, world!"

However, if I use a print letter statement in if condition it prints correct letters.

Comment: You're mixing `print` statements (that print encoded letters) with a `return` statement (that *returns* the original input). You'll want to build a new list based on the encoded letters.

Comment: You should probably ask on the course mitx forum

Answer (score 3):

Rebinding the current iteration variable doesn't modify the list (hopefully - that would be a very annoying side effect).

Also, rebinding `coder` to `coder_dict` is useless, and you can iterate on a string. To make a long story short, the solution is to rebuild a list with the modified letters... and since you don't really need the list itself, you can as well just use a generator expression:

```
def apply_coder(text, coder):
    return ''.join(coder.get(letter, letter) for letter in text)
```

Answer (score 0):

By changing `letter` you are **not** changing anything in the list `text_list`. You should build a new list instead of the result of the encoding:

```
def apply_coder(text, coder):
    ret_val = []
    coder_dict = coder
    for letter in text:
        if letter in coder_dict:
            letter = coder_dict[letter]
            print letter
        ret_val.append(letter)
    return ''.join(ret_val)
```

And that also means you don't first have to make `text` into a list.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `letter = coder_dict[letter]` just looks up the `letter` key in `coder_dict` and assigns that value to `letter`, which doesn't change it. The it prints that letter. However, you're not modifying `text_list` at all. There are several ways to do this, such as with `enumerate`:

```
def apply_coder(text, coder):
    text_list = list(text)
    for val,letter in enumerate(text_list):
        text_list[val] = coder.get(letter, letter)
    return ''.join(text_list)
```

This will enumerate the `list`, then reassign each indexed element with the letter lookup if possible or the letter itself otherwise, then `join()` the `list` and `return` it.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to a question asked not long ago, about encrypting/swapping letters.

The code below is provided by alec_djinn

```
decrypted = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' #normal alphabet
encrypted = 'MNBVCXZLKJHGFDSAPOIUYTREWQ' #your "crypted" alphabet

#Encription
text = 'cryptme' #the string to be crypted
encrypted_text = ''
for letter in text:
    encrypted_text += encrypted[decrypted.find(letter)]
print encrypted_text
#will print BOWAUFC

#Decription
text = encrypted_text #"BOWAUFC" in this example
decrypted_text = ''
for letter in text:
    decrypted_text += decrypted[encrypted.find(letter)]
print decrypted_text
#will print cryptme
```

A link to this is provided below as well.

[How to 'encrypt' a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731952/how-to-encrypt-a-file/30732211#30732211)